# How do I write a loop that makes each piece of an array that can be any amount of pieces long, into individual variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Currently I have this

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)
```

I need each piece of the array to be individual variables and I cant just do `var cardOne = arr[1], var cardTwo = arr[2]` etc because I don't know how many cards they will have.

So I got this to work

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)

var sum = 0;
var i;
arr[1] = arr[1].replace(/-/g, "");
for (i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++) {
sum += parseInt(arr[1].substr(i, 1)); }
console.log(arr[1], "=", sum);
```

Now i just need a way to get that last part starting with (var sum = 0) to go for every piece of the array so i can run an if/ else with them to see which one has the highest sum

Comment: You can't. Moreover, you don't want to. Just use `arr`.

Comment: *"I need each piece of the array to be individual variables..."*. No, you really don't need that. If you don't know how many cards there will be, how will making them variables help that situation?

Comment: This sure looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to accomplish that made you think dynamic variable names would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you're fine with arrays instead of variables. ^^
But I'm not sure I really understand your question... You're getting card numbers and you want to sum all the digits of each card to see which one has the biggest sum?

If I understood correctly (which I don't think I did), then this is the code you want:

```js
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++) arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  card = arr[i].replace(/-/g,"");
  sum = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < card.length; j++) {
    sum += parseInt(card[j]);
  }
  console.log("Sum of card "+i+" = "+sum);
}
```

Comment: var s = "5246-9346-7341-8534";
var sum = 0;
var i;
s = s.replace(/-/g, "");
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(s.substr(i, 1));
}
console.log(s, "=", sum); //it runs like this//

 var sum = 0;
 var i;
 arr[1] = arr[1].replace(/-/g, "");
 for (i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++) {
 sum += parseInt(s.substr(i, 1)); }
 console.log(arr[1], "=", sum); //does not run like this

Comment: this site does not let you comment easily

Comment: Would you please add the code snippet to your question instead (by editing it)? It would be much much easier for me to read.

Comment: I expanded it a bit

Comment: I have no problem bearing with you. The whole point of StackOverflow is to try to help people in need, as far as I know. ^^